# Not-an-exception exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception

Does java has library exception class which means actually not an error, but good termination? I know I can make my own class or use `null`, but wish to know.

**EDIT 1**

I want to use exception object as an old fashion return code for a method, so I need something equivalent to `ERROR_SUCCESS` code in Win32 API.

Comment: Why would you need that? If there is no error condition, then you should not throw an exception at all.

Comment: Wait you want an `exception` to say that.. nothing happened? (we must be using different dictionaries here) Well you certainly can abuse the system in that way, but goodness, no there does not exist such a thing in the standard library and I can't think of a single good reason why anyone would want to do that.

Comment: How can it be an `Exception` if it is not an exception? Sounds like a paradox to me.

Comment: @adarshr Maybe it's one of the applications where successful termination is an exception.

Comment: @DanielFischer Just doesn't sound right to me. That application certainly has had a confused past then.

Comment: @adarshr I think Daniel was making a somewhat mean (but highly entertaining) joke there: I.e. the best thing that could happen when running such an application is that it terminates as soon as possible ;)

Comment: I like @Voo's version better than mine. I just meant that it normally crashes, so successful termination is ... an exception.

Comment: Do you want the exceptions for logging and tracing? You might take a look at Log4J.

Comment: `ERROR_SUCCESS` was always my favorite example of why return error codes are an exceedingly stupid idea. You really don't need it: If an error happens, throw an exception, if none happens do nothing - that's the whole point of exceptions, separating error and success paths from each other.

Comment: @Voo `ERROR_SUCCESS` exists despite the fact someone uses it as an example of evil. Appropriate design patterns can be used in heterogeneous applications then, for example.

Comment: @Suzan `ERROR_SUCCESS` exists because the Win32 API was written in C and had to be compatible with C anyhow (MS went so far as to basically implement their own C with classes in the 90s). Also c++ exceptions had even more problems back then than now. Mixing error codes and exceptions is an extremely bad idea and abusing exceptions as error codes is even worse - you're mixing two orthogonal paradigms. The whole idea about exceptions is to separate the error path from the normal code. If you want to you can write C in every language-nothing stops you from writing an API with error codes in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question:  No.  There is no standard Java exception that means "this is a normal termination".

If you wanted to, you *could* define a custom exception that meant this for your application.

### However,

...  using an exception for "normal control flow" goes against the strong recommendations of the Java designers, and a Java "Best Practice" rule that has pretty much universal acceptance.  This is not to say you should NEVER do this.  It is just that the cases where it is justifiable to do this are VERY RARE.  (And you'd need to take special steps to avoid grossly inefficient code ... )

Anyway, the fact that it is (almost) always a terrible idea to use exceptions for normal flow control explains why a standard exception was never created.  The Java designers clearly didn't want to appear to be encouraging this practice.

Answer (score 6):

Exceptions in Java are meant to be used for abnormal termination only. Using them to flag correct termination should be considered really bad practice.

You might use return values instead.

Comment: +1: There are some non-exception XxxxException classes in Java, but its rarely done and a bad idea IMHO. e.g.

Comment: @Peter, can you give me an example pls?

Comment: On the one hand you have classes like java.rmi.ServerError, java.sql.SQLWarning which are Exceptions but don't end in Exception, CodeException which is not an Exception, and AttributeException, FlavourException and URIException which are interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to a "good termination" signal I can think of is not an exception, but a call to [`System.exit(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) with `0` as argument, to indicate to the operating system that the program ended successfully. From the javadocs:

> Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine. The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination. This method calls the exit method in class Runtime. This method never returns normally.

As has been pointed out, an exception is *not* to be used to inform of a "good termination", quite the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

No. Exception means exceptional situation. You should structure your program flow so that exceptions are thrown only for exceptional situations, rather than on the normal flow.

So, if you want to return "success": return `true` or some enum `Result.SUCCESS`.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are mean to denote that something went wrong. Different exceptions depict different items which went wrong and will thus cause the program to terminate if not handled. Something successfully finishing is not an exception.

I think what you need to do is to either return a particular value, or else, make your application fire some sort of `event`. In this case throwing exception is not (at least for me) recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you define as "good termination" I guess - is a security exception good because it stopped someone from hacking your system? It's not really an error, but it is an abnormal situation that you need to handle.

In general exceptions are designed to be used for **exceptional conditions only** (which may or may not be an error in your code - it could mean that some resource is unavailable, or a security check failed etc.)

If you are using exceptions for regular control flow (i.e. they are getting thrown in normal, expected circumstances) then you are probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean an [InterrupedException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html)? This one is thrown, when you wish to terminate a thread gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

As some other responses said, when there is no exception, nothing is raised.

Therefore, you can just your code for the "no-exception" into the try block after the rest of instructions. Something like:

```
try{
  //code here

  //code of no exception
}catch(Exception e){
  //nothing or exception code
}
```

or you can just create your own exception by doing a class that extends Exception